# Get email of an account using google plus and how to check the session while logging using OAuth

Tags: android, email, session, webview, google-oauth

I am using webview to authenticate the user using this https://github.com/imellon/Google-Plus-Android-Sample/blob/master/src/com/imellon/android/googleplus/OAuthActivity.java to access my app and after he his succesfully authorized I need to get the user email.

I couldn't  find out the way to get the email.

This is what I have now:

```
private void retrieveProfile() {
    try {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

        SharedPreferencesCredentialStore credentialStore = SharedPreferencesCredentialStore
                .getInstance(prefs);

        AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = credentialStore.read();

        GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                accessTokenResponse.accessToken, transport, jsonFactory,
                SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_ID,
                SharedPreferencesCredentialStore.CLIENT_SECRET,
                accessTokenResponse.refreshToken);

        Builder b = Plus.builder(transport, jsonFactory)
                .setApplicationName("Simple-Google-Plus/1.0");
        b.setHttpRequestInitializer(accessProtectedResource);
        Plus plus = b.build();
        profile = plus.people().get("me").execute();

        updateViews();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I get the Id, name and url

```
private void updateViews() {
    Drawable image = loadImage(this, profile.getImage().getUrl());
    profile_photo.setImageDrawable(image);
    profile_id.setText("Id: " + profile.getId());
    profile_name.setText("Name: " + profile.getDisplayName());
    profile_url.setText("Url: " + profile.getUrl());
}
```

And finally each time when he logins to my app how do I check the session ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `profile.getEmails()` as documented in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/plus/v1/java/latest/. The result is a list of type `java.util.List<Person.Emails>`.

You need to make sure your client asked for the scope `plus.profile.emails.read` to allow your client to retrieve that information.